# Is there any way to rotate a PDF file created using PdfDocument canvas in android

Tags: android, pdf, android-canvas

Is there any way to rotate a PDF file created using PdfDocument canvas in android or is there any way to rotate a pdf file before saving to phone on android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. Use `canvas.rotate(90);` before drawing anything in the canvas of PDF document.

```
canvas.save();
// rotate with respect to center of the page.
canvas.rotate(90, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
canvas.draw(/*whatever*/);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Is there any way where i can entirely rotate a pdf before saving ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to rotate all pages at once. You will need to do it for each page.

Comment: If you are rotating the entire document, there is no need to save and restore the canvas. You can just call `canvas.rotate(/*params*/)` before drawing anything in a page.